# A for loop in MYSQL WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to have a forloop in WHERE clause, something like

```
SELECT
  name,
  surname,
  id
FROM person
WHERE (while(x < 5)) = id
```

then the result will have id's from 1 to 4. The 5 can have a list of values or an array.

Is this even possible?

ps. this example can be done by using WHERE 5 > id

I was just wondering if this can be done with a loop, I will be using this query snippet in jasper report

Comment: It doesn't make sense. The `WHERE` clause is for establishing predicates about the columns in each row of the result set. You do that with comparisons, `EXISTS`, `IN` and other tools. I can't think of any situation where a loop makes sense. Perhaps if you could propose an example that *isn't* trivially re-writable as a normal predicate, we might be able to help. If you can't think of such an example, it kind of demonstrates the point that it's unnecessary.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226447/passing-sql-in-parameter-list-in-jasperreport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
SELECT name, surname, id 
FROM person
WHERE id in(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

If this list of numbers comes from an array or a list you can compose this list from your front end application, or create a temp table from those values and `JOIN` the table with it.

Comment: Yes, but the values inside IN clause came from a list or an array.?

Comment: @user1816978 You can compose this `IN` clause from your application using these values that come from the array or a list, or use a temp table and `JOIN` the table with it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it using WHERE clause. You need a construct that returns the value to use it in a condition.

- The WHILE statement returns nothing, it is just a statements list.
- The condition `5 > id` returns value that can be used in WHERE clause.

Note, in stored procedure you could do something like this -

```
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE i < 5 DO
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = i;
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
```

...but it is not efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment:

> *The 5 can have a list of values or an array*

You might be after something like this:

```
select id, name, surname
from person
where find_in_set(id, '1,2,3,4') > 0;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7186d/3

Answer (score 1):

You can use BETWEEN command if you know from where to where you want to get data. As like following command ...

```
   SELECT name, surname, id FROM person WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 5 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple query with where condition like this and it is what exactly you are asking for i mean alternative of loop.  This does not require loops when the query is executed it executes like loop

```
SELECT
    p.name, 
    p.surname, 
    p.id
FROM person p
WHERE p.id < 5
```

this will check the records with id starting from 1 to 4