# Passing a String parameter to a subreport Dataset

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to pass a parameter from Java to a subreport. The problem is when I got to check all the values inside an IN. The parameter `$P{Itens}` is coming on this format(1234,5678,9012) and it's String.

[image: Image from JasperSoft]

How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing SQL "IN" parameter list in jasperreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226447/passing-sql-in-parameter-list-in-jasperreport)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the parameter type as **List** from Java to report carrying all possible values. Afterwards, edit your report *jrxml* and set parameter $P{Itens} datatype to **java.util.List** instead of String.

In report query, replace `iae.COD_PECA in $P{Itens}` with `$X{IN, iae.COD_PECA, $P{Itens}}`.  Here, $X{} is a built-in support provided by JasperReports for SQL clause functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked perfectly! On my aplicattion I must pass the parameters in ArrayList as well, right?

Comment: Happy to help! Please mark it as accepted answer and yes, you must pass the values in `java.util.Collection` (ArrayList is fine) to report.